# Same-Origin Policy: Understanding Deny Read

Tags: javascript, html, security, same-origin-policy

[This MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/08/28/same-origin-policy-part-1-no-peeking/) explains that READS are not permitted by the `same-origin policy`.

Specifically, it says:

> **Webpage from Origin A:**
>
> - May include (execute) a frame pointed at a HTML page from “B”
> - Must **not** be permitted to get the inner HTML of that frame

How can another html file be "included (executed)", without the content of it being accessed?

What does "included (executed)" even mean in this context?

Comment: The human being (or dog) looking at the rendered result of loading the frame can see the content, but Origin A JavaScript cannot access it at all.

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy. The browser here prevents scripts from any other origin to interact with the html? It is interesting how it can parse and show it on demand, cross-origin, but at the same time be able to block any access to the content.

Comment: The policies are primarily about controlling what JavaScript from a particular origin can do with content from another origin.

Comment: @Pointy Let's say the user was already authenticated on his bank with his browser, a session still live via his cookies. A malicious script could redisplay his bank account information to the user, right? Hehe, I guess that isn't very useful to the hacker, but in theory that could work? Could the hacker not then use some kind of screen / pixel analysis to read the content?

Comment: Yes, the attack site could do that  (assuming the bank site isn't protecting itself with an `X-Frame-Options` header), but no it cannot get at the results of the browser rendering the content to the user's screen. If you figure out a way to do that, you've found a major security flaw in a browser.

Comment: @Pointy Now that I understand it better, the MSDN article linked above actually mentions a getPixel functionality, and why it is a terrible idea. I guess that is for the exact reason we discussed. To avoid a malicious script from reading cross-origin content rendered by a browser.

Comment: And CSRF is basically the situation you described, but with XHR. The attacker attempts to "piggy-back" on an existing session, so the bank has to require some sort of token that (due to the SOP) the attacking site can't get.

Comment: @Pointy Last question: Is it right that SOP does not deal with XSS in any way? XSS is injection of scripts via user input, and SOP is preventing a page/script from READing resources cross-origins. The two do not relate. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, XSS is part of a broader class of problems and doesn't involve the SOP.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referring to the fact that the user viewing the page can see the content of the iframe, but scripts running on the framing page cannot access the content of the framed page. Consider analogously that an `<img>` tag will show an image from any origin to a user, but scripts within the page that contains the `<img>` tag might not be able to read the contents of the loaded image.

This is important because the framed page is from a different origin and was fetched using the user's cookies from that origin. Suppose the framed page was `mail.google.com`: certainly I don't want any random webpage to read the contents of my inbox simply by loading it in an iframe. However, merely *showing* the page to me, the user who happens to be logged in to my mail service, is harmless.